# Raspberry pi wifi hotspot in nodejs configuration

Tags: node.js, raspberry-pi, raspberry-pi3, raspbian

I need some help on my project with Rpi.

1. The RPi should create wifi network
2. This network is not connected to the internet
3. This network should redirect the users to a local nodejs website
4. All of this need to be launched on reboot

For 1 & 2.  I have found [This tutorial](https://andrewmichaelsmith.com/2013/08/raspberry-pi-wi-fi-honeypot/)  but as I reboot

- It create the wifi hotspot (good)
- I lose ethernet connection for ssh access (bad) 
  to the pi
- AND if i try to connect with my Android phone, the IP configuration failed. (bad++)

For 3. i have seen [this](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/41369/wifi-hotspot-with-redirect-to-html?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa) about iptables.

For 4. "sudo update-rc.d node path/to/index.js" should do the trick, I think.

For your understanding, I use :

- Raspberry Pi 3B
- RASPBIAN STRETCH LITE Version: March 2018, Release date:2018-03-13, Kernel version:4.9

Can you help me to configure this hotspot ?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look into how https://github.com/sabhiram/raspberry-wifi-conf has implemented their access point; it includes a lightweight webserver page that can be accessed through the access point and a startup script for launching at boot.

The library is specifically for connecting a pi to wifi through an 'ad-hoc' style network (like a lot of IoT devices do these days) but could be adapted to whatever you had in mind. Nodejs based.

Comment: You are a life saver ! THANKS !